# xargs failed to run one script in sub-folder

Tags: xargs

```
cd folder1
ls | xargs -t -I {} {}/MyScript.sh param1 param2 &
```

The above command doesn't work.

I am not sure why {} is not replaced by sub-folder.
How can I fix the issue?

summary for the question:
below works:
ls | xargs -t -I '{}' ksh '{}'/MyScript.ksh param1 param2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, this doesn't work:

```
ls | xargs -t -I {} {}/MyScript.sh param1 param2
```

But this does:

```
ls | xargs -t -I {} sh {}/MyScript.sh param1 param2
```

A close reading of the man page reveals why:

```
xargs  [...] [command [initial-arguments]]

-I replace-str
     Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments
     with names read from standard input.
```

If the {} is first, it is part of the `command`, not the `initial-arguments`, and thus is not replaced. So, you need to arrange things so that the {} is always part of the arguments, and not the command. In your case, this can easily be done by using `sh {}/MyScript.sh` rather than invoking `MyScript` directly.

(Note: I'm using bash here, where `{}` with nothing inside it doesn't need to be quoted. Other shells may need to quote it.)

Comment: ToxicFrog, Thanks very much!

Comment: Below command works for me now:
   ls | xargs -t -I '{}' ksh '{}'/MyScript.ksh param1 param2